# Node Webkit: forced shutdown of a Windows 8 machine from kiosk app

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, node-webkit, nw.js

I have an node webkit based kiosk app which is running on a Windows 8 x64 machine. How can a programmatically shutdown the whole system? The shutdown process shall be initiated from a cheat-key in the kiosk app.

Im faced with these questions:

- how to close the kiosk app itself? explicit - right before calling the shutdown command or implicit (let windows kill it during shutdown)
- how to prevent any interrupting warnings from windows?

The kiosk app itself doesn't store any data (read only) so it is safe to kill it at any time.

Answer (score 0):

got it! this code works well for me:

`var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var child = exec( 'shutdown -s -f -t 10 -c "Shutdown system in 10s!"' );`